# Add newline to Oh My ZSH Theme

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to add a newline to my existing Oh My ZSH theme but can't figure out what to add or where it should be added / changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the proper place to change one's prompt is in the theme itself.  On my system, it's in `~/.oh=my-zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme`.  I added a `\n➜` there:
Find this section:

```
# End the prompt, closing any open segments

prompt_end() {
  if [[ -n $CURRENT_BG ]]; then
    echo -n " % 

{%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR"
  else
    echo -n "%{%k%}"
  fi
  echo -n "\n➜%{%f%}"
  CURRENT_BG=''
}
```

Comment: The code formatter in stackoverflow seems difficult.  I'm sorry for the badly formatted code.  Is there a limit to how much code can be formatted as code?

Comment: When you change the theme directly, you will loose your config when update it.

Comment: Although I'll stick with the "override in `.zshrc`" approach. It's still very helpful to remind people to look into the original theme file, learn how the `prompt_end` is implemented and know what to override and where to append. Thanks!

Answer (score 108):

I was actually searching for the same answer. But my needs was a little more specific since I only wanted to add a newline in the [agnoster](https://gist.github.com/agnoster/3712874) theme, the one I'm using now.

In my research, I find a lot of forked themes that already do it, but I thought that this was an overkill solution for only add a new line.

So I read the `agnoster` code and come up with this simple solution of overwrite the `prompt_end()` function in my `.zshrc` file.

To do it, just add the code bellow in your `.zshrc` file:

```
prompt_end() {
  if [[ -n $CURRENT_BG ]]; then
      print -n "%{%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR"
  else
      print -n "%{%k%}"
  fi

  print -n "%{%f%}"
  CURRENT_BG='' 

  #Adds the new line and ➜ as the start character.
  printf "\n ➜";
}
```

Hope it helps you to have a clue on how to customize your chosen theme.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice work. Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: When i do this, my cursor alignment goes off :/ Like it is moved a bit to the left. Anyone else with a similar issue?

Comment: Seems like I had issues getting this to work, and believe moving this override to after "source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh" fixed it.

Comment: Nice work, thank you I was looking for this

Comment: does this work for the default `robbyrussell` theme?

Comment: For the default (robbyrussell) theme check my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77599393/8070550

Answer (score 14):

Here is my version which works just like the others, but repeats the last symbol of the previous line so that it imitates the exact prompt that agnoster gives you:

```
prompt_end() {
  if [[ -n $CURRENT_BG ]]; then
    echo -n " %{%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR"
  else
    echo -n "%{%k%}"
  fi
  echo -n "\n%{%F{$CURRENT_BG}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR%{%f%}"
  CURRENT_BG=''
}
```

Note: If you do not want to modify the library's source code, you can also just put this function into your `~/.zshrc` file near the end. It will then be used over the library-provided function.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

How about this

```sh
NEWLINE=$'\n'
PROMPT='%n ${NEWLINE} $ '
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update your agnoster theme because it will be overwritten by an update, you can create a new theme and place it under `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` directory. The "custom" directory is excluded by git.

Answer (score 0):

If your using `PROMPT` and appending to it, like in senpai theme, just do:

```
        if [[ $SENPAI_SHOW_K8S == true ]]; then
                PROMPT+="\$(k8s_info)
 ${yellow} —————» %f"
        fi
```

And you'll get a multiline prompt:

```
    [19:28:02] ~ ⎈:default-demo2-gke
      —————»  ns:default ❯ ls /etc
```

Simplified:

```
PROMPT='multi
line
prompt'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default theme (*robbyrussell*) a good approach is to overwrite the *ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX* or *PROMPT* in the `~/.zshrc` file.

Somewhere after the line `# User configuration` you put something like this:

```
OMZ_NEW_LINE_FORMAT=$'\n ➜ '
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX+=$OMZ_NEW_LINE_FORMAT
# Uncomment if you want to move the command line to a new line always 
#PROMPT+=$OMZ_NEW_LINE_FORMAT
```

You simply use the `+=` so that the command is left as it is, yet you concatenate the new line `\n` char and I put an arrow (`➜`) and some spacing, but you can use whatever you like.

The difference between changing the ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX and PROMPT variables is that in the former (ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX) it only creates a new line when you are in a git repo, while the later it shows a new line always.

If you want to observe the content of the theme you can check it like this:

```
cat ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [gvsrepins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420898), but didn't want to have to copy in the existing `prompt_end` definition. (I use a git submodule to load the [Agnoster](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme) theme, and don't want to have to keep code updated in more than one spot).

What I did was add a new segment, and out it at the end of `AGNOSTER_PROMPT_SEGMENTS`, like so:

```
prompt_newline() {
    printf "\n ➜";
}

AGNOSTER_PROMPT_SEGMENTS+=prompt_newline
```

After that, I get a very similar result, with the arrow on a new line *beneath* the statusline, without having to update my copy of existing code when/if theme internals change!

Your theme might have something similar, a way to add a "segment" to the prompt.

Note: Agnoster seems to add a space between segments, so my arrow character isn't on the far left of the window. This is how I like it anyway, feels less cramped, but you may want to make more changes for your preferred setup.